# API to record audio with specific volume on Android

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I want to make an app to record using MediaRecorder with certain volume set by user.

Is there any possibility to set the volume when recording? I try to see in MediaRecorder API but i can't find setVolume or something like that..

Is there any work around? Or any post process that i have to do to make it happen?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it while recording, but you can set the volume while playing with the setVolume(float, float) method on MediaPlayer.

Comment: But in that case if other app play my file audio it won't have the same volume when i play it in my app.
Is there any work around?

Comment: There is no standard way to pass desired volume information between 2 apps.
Are you the developer of the 2 apps?

Comment: No, i just want that other app can also play my audio with the same volume that the user desired.